# How to set the "Link To Previous" Setting for a Header via OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I have created a Word docx file using the Telerik Report generator. Each of the pages contains a header. When I open up the docx, it looks good initially...

Now the headers on all of the pages are output properly, **however**, if I make a change on the header, that change is not reflected on all of the subsequent headers. Turns out this is because the headers are not "linked to the previous" header. This screenshot shows the toolbar button "Link to Previous" being enabled, plus the "Same as Previous" decoration on the header itself to indicate that this header would share the exact same content as the first header.

[image]

Now I am trying to figure out how to set this programatically via OpenXML. This led me to some similar code samples, for example [Replace the header in a word processing document (Open XML SDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-replace-the-header-in-a-word-processing-document). From what I gather, the approach would be to find the ID of the first header, and then in all of the sections of document, you remove the existing header and replace it with a reference to the first header.

I came up with this:

```
private void FixDocument(string outputFile)
{
    using (var wdDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(outputFile, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wdDoc.MainDocumentPart;
        var firstHeader = mainPart.HeaderParts.FirstOrDefault();
        var firstHeaderId = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(firstHeader);

        // Get SectionProperties and Replace HeaderReference and FooterRefernce with new Id

        var sections = mainPart.Document.Descendants<SectionProperties>();    
        foreach (var section in sections)
        {
            // Delete existing references to headers and footers
            section.RemoveAllChildren<HeaderReference>();
            // Create the new header and footer reference node
            section.PrependChild<HeaderReference>(new HeaderReference() { Id = firstHeaderId, Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default });
        }              
    }
}
```

And after saving the document and opening it up, it appears that a) the original headers are still there, and none of them are linked to the first one.

I am not sure where I went wrong - any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first section in your document has the desired headers and/or footers then I think in order to get "**Link to Previous**" on the rest of the sections you just need to remove any header and/or footer that is specified on them.

In other words, try this:

```
private void FixDocument(string outputFile)
{
    using (var wdDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(outputFile, true))
    {
        var mainPart = wdDoc.MainDocumentPart;
        var sections = mainPart.Document.Descendants<SectionProperties>().Skip(1);

        foreach (var section in sections)
        {
            section.RemoveAllChildren<HeaderReference>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great! One item in my header was the page number. Now of course all of the headers are sharing the same page number because of the link to previous. Any thoughts on how at least allow that to increment?

Comment: @flyte what kind of item is it, is it a Run element or a Field? If you place a PAGE field then it should work as expected, different page number for each page.